# Connect to remote websocket angularjs

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am trying to connect to a remote push API websocket (in the client / browser, not in the backend) and log the live data in the console. I have been searching for a while and can't find any examples of this.

This is the API I'm trying to connect to: https://poloniex.com/support/api/

I want to `subscribe` to the `ticker` channel and log the data in console.

I have istalled socket.io in order to accomplish this, and here is the code I have so far:

```js
var socket = io.connect('wss://api.poloniex.com ');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('ticker');
});
```

Chrome inspector is showing error, repeatedly every second or two: `https://api.poloniex.com%20/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LqCBLTn net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

How can I get live data from this websocket API?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the URL: `'wss://api.poloniex.com '`

`net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` indicates that the host name couldn't be resolved. So you should look at the host name you're trying to reach. `api.poloniex.com%20` could not be resolved because you probably don't have a domain registered with a `.com%20` TLD! Simply remove the space in the first line of your snippet and, assuming your DNS records are setup accordingly, you shouldn't get `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` anymore.